# Icon for rename button

Tags: icons

To add some context to this question, I am currently developing an iOS application and need some advise on the interface.

What is the most suitable icon for a 'rename' button?

When this button is pressed, a dialogue appears prompting the user for a new name for the file. As the application also has the ability to edit files, I want to avoid confusion between the two functions.

I am currently struggling to think of anything that would work, so might end up using text instead.

Answer (score 6):

To make it easy to understand, you should simply use the most commonly used "typing cursor icon". (ex: http://www.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/256/Rename-icon.png). And you may stilize it by apps colors and effects.

Also you may take a look at these articles at the end of this [Turkish blog post about "designing an icon."](http://www.barisoztekin.com/blog/?p=319)

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx)
- [TUTSplus](http://psd.tutsplus.com/articles/7-principles-of-effective-icon-design/)
- [turbomilk](http://turbomilk.com/blog/cookbook/criticism/10_mistakes_in_icon_design/)
- [Fedora Icon Guidelines](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Artwork/EchoIconGuidelines)

Comment: MSDN - Icons: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx

Comment: 7 Principles of Effective Icon Design: http://psd.tutsplus.com/articles/7-principles-of-effective-icon-design/

Comment: 10 Mistakes in Icon Design: http://turbomilk.com/blog/cookbook/criticism/10_mistakes_in_icon_design/

Comment: Fedora Echo Icon Guidelines: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Artwork/EchoIconGuidelines